# How can I promise so that way I can use sentMessage in this area. DISCORD.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I replace [the message the bot sent] with sentMessage?

````js
client.guilds.get("588125693225992195")
  .channels
  .find(ch => ch.name === 'order-requests')
  .send(richemb)
  .then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react(''))
  .catch(() => console.error('Failed to react.'))

const filter = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === ''

message.awaitReactions(filter)
  .then([themessagethebotsent].delete(0500))
  .catch(console.error);```
````

Answer (score 0):

The [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of `sentMessage` is within the `then()` callback. This means that it can't be accessed outside of that callback.

You have two main solutions. Keeping your current setup, you could place the code that needs `sentMessage` inside the callback. Or, you could use the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for a better flow. Note that it can only be used in [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Example 1:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.get('588125693225992195');
const channel = guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name == 'order-requests');

channel.send(richemb)
  .then(sentMessage => {
    sentMessage.react('');

    message.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '')
      .then(() => sentMessage.delete(0500));
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Example 2:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.get('588125693225992195');
const channel = guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'order-requests');

try {
  const sentMessage = await channel.send(richemb);
  await sentMessage.react('');

  await sentMessage.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '');
  await sentMessage.delete(0500);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```